# How can i pass an array to an object during its initialisation in java? this gives me an error num can't be resolved (last line of code)

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I want to know why the following code throws an error like num can't be resolved although I have already declared an array and initialised it. I am trying to pass an array to an object during creation of an object.... is it not allowed or there is some other error in my code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Search {


public Search(int x[])
{
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        System.out.println("inside a constructer"+x[i]);    

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    Integer  num[] = new Integer[10];    
    Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Eneter the 10 integers:");

     for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
     {
         System.out.println("Enter the "+(i+1)+" number:");
         num[i]=sc.nextInt();
     }
     for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
     System.out.println(num[j]); 

    }

    Search obj=new Search(num);

}
```

Comment: Always give the COMPLETE and EXACT error message when you ask a question.

Comment: The line `Search obj=new Search(num);` is not in any method.  Since there is no class-level declaration of `num` it is undefined.

Comment: (Your text editor most likely has a feature where it will reformat code based on `{}` characters.  If you use that it will make missing `{` or `}` characters stick out like a sore thumb.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Integer and int are 2 different things.  Change

`Integer num[] = new Integer[10];` to `int num[] = new int[10];`

int is a primitive type while Integer is a object that wraps the int primitive type.

Also in your constructor don't hard code 10 in your loop do x.length instead.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num[] = new int[10];

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Eneter the 10 integers:");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the " + (i + 1) + " number:");
            num[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            System.out.println(num[j]);

        }

        Search obj = new Search(num);
    }


public class Search {

    public Search(int x[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            System.out.println("inside a constructer" + x[i]);

    }

}
```

Comment: it doesnt work... again showing the same error      ..can u plz check if i am writing last line of the code properly?

Comment: The code works fine for me after changing Integer to int and adding { in second for loop.

Comment: it was a mistake ....it was not a delibrate action .. i am sorry.. i am unable to upvote u right now..may b next time .. sorry again

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you wanted an open curly brace { after the second for.
The way it is now, the line
    Search obj=new Search(num)

is not in the main method.

Answer (score 0):

It could also work with Integer because of automatical cast between int and Integer.

```
public class Search {



public Search(Integer[] x)
{
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        System.out.println("inside a constructer"+x[i]);


}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

Integer[]  num = new Integer[10];

Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Eneter the 10 integers:");

 for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
 {
 System.out.println("Enter the "+(i+1)+" number:");
    num[i]=sc.nextInt();
 }
 for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
 System.out.println(num[j]); 
 Search obj=new Search(num);
 }

}
```